# How do I avoid assembly converter build error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

Attempting to build a Mixed Reality project I'm getting an (extremely long) error message, the meat of which is:

> Error:
>   The command [...]\UWP\Unity\Tools\AssemblyConverter.exe" -platform=uap -lock=... 
>   exited with code 1.

This is happening in Unity 2017.3.0f (but was happening with the previous version as well) and Visual Studio 17.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we have no leverage on this tool. The following unofficial workaround was published by a user: perhaps you should have a look to see if it can help you until you upgrade to a newer Unity (but it seems that they will only support IL2CPP builds going forward):

https://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2018/05/fixing-unitytoolsassemblyconverterexe.html